# Removing item ref from Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to remove an item from the list, but the following code does not work:

```
exports.removeOldItems = functions.database.ref('/chat/usersOnline/{userId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
      const snap = event.data;
      if (!snap.exists()) return;

      snap.forEach(it => {                                                                                 
        if ( condition ) {
          it.ref.remove();   <---- THIS NOT WORK
        }
      })

    });
```

The statement "it.ref.remove()" runs but is not removing the children item. What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

I do not know why, but using parent.once(...) solves the problem:

```
exports.removeOldItems = functions.database.ref('/chat/usersOnline/{userId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
      if (!event.data.exists()) return;
      const parentRef = event.data.ref.parent;

      return parentRef.once('value').then(users => {
        users.forEach(function(tabs) {                               
          tabs.forEach(instance => {                                  
            if ( condition ) {                                          
              instance.ref.remove();
            }
          })
        });
      });

    });
```

I used the following example as a guide: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/limit-children/functions/index.js

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Doesn't it get called? Adding a log statement might help to determine that. Does the `if` statement evaluate to `false`? It's hard for us to remotely debug your function for you. It might be easier if you first write the code as a local node.js script using the Firebase Admin SDK and ensure it works there. The interaction between your code and the database will be the same locally as it will be remotely, only the trigger is different in the Cloud Functions environment.

Comment: The statement it.ref.remove() is not removing the item. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

this might be happening because your are not returning a promise.
try something like that.

```
exports.removeOldItems = functions.database.ref('/chat/usersOnline/{userId}')
.onWrite(event => {
  const snap = event.data;
  var itemstoremove = [];
  if (!snap.exists()) return;

  snap.forEach(it => {                                                                                 
    if ( condition ) {
      itemstoremove.push(it.ref.remove());   <---- THIS NOT WORK
    }
  })
return Promise.all(itemstoremove);

});
```